# OSX 10.11 El Capitan - setting boot device property not working

Tags: applescript

I am working on a dualboot system and used the following applescript to set the startup volume:

```
    tell application "Finder" to if not (disk "SoundHD" exists) then do shell script "diskutil mount " & last word of (do shell script "diskutil list | grep 'Apple_HFS SoundHD'")

do shell script "bless -mount \"/Volumes/SoundHD\" -setBoot --nextonly" with administrator privileges

display notification "Next Boot: SoundHD" with title "Neustart"
```

Since El Capitan the script won't work anymore and I am getting the following error message in the Script Editor:

```
tell application "Finder"
   exists disk "SoundHD"
            --> true
    end tell
    tell current application
        do shell script "bless -mount \"/Volumes/SoundHD\" -setBoot --nextonly" with administrator privileges
            --> error "Could not set boot device property: 0xe00002bc" number 3
    Ergebnis:
    error "Could not set boot device property: 0xe00002bc" number 3
```

Are there some new changes in the bless command?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would blame System integrity protection but i am not sure

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must first disable System Integrity Protection.

1. Restart the computer, then while booting, hold down Command-R to boot into
   recovery mode.
2. Once booted, navigate to the “Utilities > Terminal” in the top menu bar.
3. Enter `csrutil disable` in the terminal window and hit the return key.
4. Restart the machine and System Integrity Protection will now be disabled.

source: http://mattjanik.ca/blog/2015/10/01/refind-on-el-capitan/

Comment: Can we get some context around why this must be done and if it's a permanent solution and what are the problems with turning off SIP?

Comment: Do not disable SIP just for this. SIP there for an important reason: it prevents malware and rogue processes from modifying the core operating system.

Comment: @Karew: I don't believe there is an alternative solution. If you know otherwise don't hold back.

Comment: Also this sadly doesn't work anyway. Even after disabling SIP `bless --verbose` prints `NVRAM variable "boot-args" not set.` and it just reboots into OSX.

Comment: And apparently, macOS now REACTIVATES CSR after updates. Great. My dislike for this company grows by the minute.

Comment: SIP gets disabled for a variety of reasons. Playing Melee is one of them. Screw it, malware can already do much worse things to me without root access.